# Referring to many-to-many seeded data in a Rails fixture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I am developing a Rails 2.3.5 project for an inventory system. The main object is `Item` which has associated objects such as `State` and `Zipcode`. It also has a many-to-many association (HABTM) with `Location`; so, an `Item` can have zero, one, or many `Locations`.

I use seed data in `db/seeds.rb` to load the `State`, `Zipcode`, and `Location` data, as that data is the same for all instances of this project.

I want to create a fixture for `Item` to help me do unit testing. This is what I have so far:

```
# items.yml
widget1:
  state_id:   <%= State.find_by_name('Utah').id %> 
  zipcode_id: <%= Zipcode.find_by_name('00000').id %>
  locations_id: <%= Location.find_by_name('123 Main Street').id %>
```

The `state_id` and `zipcode_id` work fine. My problem is the `locations_id` line. I do not know how to specify in the fixture file the id's for a many-to-many association.

Answer (score 1):

For a many-to-many association you need an intermediate table which connects the two tables. So in this case, you'd have an `items` table, a `locations` table, and a third table `items_locations` which has two columns, `item_id` and `location_id` (or potentially more, depending on the specific case).

In the models, you would usually specify a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association for this purpose.

The `items` table doesn't have any column referencing the `locations` in this case, so you don't need to add one in the fixture. You don't need a separate fixture for the join table either though. This document explains how you define the associations in your fixture:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Fixtures.html

So you would put something like this in your fixture:

```
locations: location1, location2, location3
```

...and then define these locations in the `locations.yml` fixture.

Comment: I have such a join table. But how do I specify the specific locations in the fixture?

Comment: I edited my answer. The document contains the information you need under `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: The locations are loaded via the seeds.rb process so I don't have a locations.yml fixtures file. In fact, I _can't_ have one as having one will cause my seed data to be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to dug out this old question, but I stumbled on the same problem (data already in the database by seeding) and was only able to fix it by this hack, which works but is very ugly and maybe error prone:

```
# items_locations.yml
some_relation:
    item_id: <%= Item.find_by_name("some name").id %>
    location_id <%= Location.find_by_name('123 Main Street').id %>
```